# regex for usernames

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to figure out how to setup a regex expression on doing the following requirements.

- Must consist at least two characters that are alpha characters a-zA-Z
- Must consist only ONE underscore or dash allowed anywhere AFTER the first check, the dash/underscore cannot be at the end as the same rule to apply as the first step
- Must be alpha-numeric characters.

Basically a good example is

Acceptable Usernames

- myusername_09
- username-09
- bw-09

Unacceptable Usernames

- bw 09
- bw--09
- bw_-09
- username__09

If any help would appreciate, this is what I had but its not working for me as what I want it to be.

```
^(?=[A-Za-z0-9])(?!.*[_-]{2})[A-Za-z0-9_-]+$
```

Comment: FYI: "regex" is a contraction of "regular expression" so "regex expression", to me, sounds kind of funny.

Comment: Thanks Campbell, for fixing my tag.  I am still new to this whole stack-overflow as a member.  Mostly came for answers that we're already asked.  But this one I couldn't get what I wanted by answers out there.

Comment: @Sean: I program in C# and I am just used to "Regex" hehe, but yes I knew that.  Thanks though just incase I didn't/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you just need to validate that the username is correct? If so, I'd use this regex:

```
^[A-Za-z]{2,}[_-]?[A-Za-z0-9]{2,}$
```

You did not say how many characters would be required after the dash or underscore; my example requires at least 2 more after. It can be altered as needed.

EDIT: I've added the `?` after the `[_-]` to account for that being optional, per your comment below.

---

Some additional information on quantifiers:

- `{N,}` means that there must be at least N characters from the preceding item to match.
- `{N}` means there must be exactly N of the preceding.
- `{N,M}` means there must be at least N, but no more than M.
- `?` means there must be 0 or 1 of the preceding.
- `+` means there must be 1 or more.
- `*` means there must be 0 or more.

Comment: Thanks, that does lead to somewhat an answer.  I apologize that I didn't state how many characters.  I am in fact using ASP.NET MVC so I have an attribute that defines the minimum and maximum amount of characters as a validation.  One thing I did forget to mention was that the underscore/dash is not required it can accept typical usernames like bw09 or username09 or even plan usernames such as 'myusername'.

Comment: Gotcha; I've edited the answer to have the _ or - be optional. Note also that as it is, this regex requires at least a 4-character user name, not counting the dash/underscore, and the first two can not be numbers. It also does not check for a maximum total length. The addition of the question mark should otherwise handle what you need fine.

Comment: ^[A-Za-z]{4,}[-_]?[A-Za-z0-9]+$ is what I ended up with for those who wanted to know.  Thanks a lot Andrew for your help.

Comment: That looks good, except that it will require that the user name starts with 4 alpha characters, not two as your req. states; so `bw09` or `bw-09` would no longer be valid user names.

Comment: Yeah I changed my mind about the starting requirement :).  I felt that 4 characters alpha characters is a good statement.  I also use Regex Buddy too, I am just not that savvy of Regex as much as I used to be.

Comment: Ahh, cool; I figured that was too obvious to have been a mistake (other than a typo). Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]{4,31}$/g
```

Comment: The definition of a valid username is very specific in the question.  This answer would apply only to  a more generic definition of a username:
1) Must start with one alpha character (instead of minimum 4). 2) Further characters are alphanumeric, plus underscore (but not hyphen, multiple underscores are allowed instead of exactly one). 3) A username is 4 to 31 characters long (the _ can be the last character).

The leading / and trailing /g  syntactic elements should be explained. They are part of the programming environment, not exactly part of the regexp itself.